# General formula for integrating analytic function with linear term

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, analytic-functions

> Given an analytic function $\, f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with no known closed formula for its antiderivative. Assume further that by some clever tricks you managed to calculate the definite integral for a fixed number $c$:
>   $$A := \int_0^c f(t) \,dt \; .$$
>   Is there a way to calculate $\int_0^c t \, f(t) \, dt$ in terms of $A$, $f$ and $f^{(n)}$?

Integration by parts yields
$$\int_0^c t \, f(t) \, dt = cA - \int_0^c \int_0^t \, f(\tau) \, d\tau \,dt \; ,$$
which made it seem plausible to me that such a formula exists.

**Related Question:** 
This problem is an abstraction of my more concrete question asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320021/closed-form-of-integration-of-modified-bessel-function-composed-with-trigonometr).

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what "calculate $\int_0^c t \, f(t) \, dt$ in terms of $A$, $f$ and $f'$" means. Your integration-by-parts formula is such a calculation, which uses only $A$ and $f$. Why is this not acceptable? What is it you are after that this does not provide?

Comment: My integration-by-parts formula is not acceptable because the antiderivative of $f$ is not known. Hence, this formula is useless as it cannot be evaluated (at least not in an obvious way).
Ultimately I just want to be able to explicitly calculate the integral $\int_{0}^c tf(t)dt$, only knowing $A$ and how to evaluate $f$, $f^{(n)}$.